# On hover/mouseOver of SVG shape add a class to a list item for 15 shape/li paired items

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, mouseover, jquery-hover

I have an SVG map with 15 different shapes that change opacity on hover. They each have their own ID and all have the same class name

```
<g>
  <a xlink:href="property-100aoa.html"><polygon id="mmAoa100" class="mmProp" fill="#1AA6C6" points="252.5,450 245,406 244,394.5 244,392 243,381 243,374.5 242,366.5 245.5,359.5 
  251,347.5 275.5,339.5 278,341 286.5,338 291,349 294,348.5 303.5,367 300,368.5 304,377.5 305,387 310,385.5 311,390.5 311.5,399 
  314.5,397 318,402 321.5,438.5 318,440.5 311,441.5 306.5,446.5 304,449.5 304,460 285.5,460   "/></a>
</g>
```

When you hover over the SVG shape I'd like to change the background of the matched property name in a list and vice versa (when you hover over the property name in the list the matching SVG shape changes).

I am new to javascript/jquery and I've tried .addClass("hover") and adding this to my css but I am having to do this for both directions (hovering over the shape vs hovering over the list item) and for all 15 different properties, resulting in 30 different functions. There has got to be a better, more efficient way to do this.

The script for just one of my list item/shape pairs is here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#mmAoa100").hover(function(){ //hover over shape
    $("#pl100aoa").addClass("hover"); //adds class to list item
}, function(){
    $('#pl100aoa').removeClass("hover"); //removes class from list item
});

$("#pl100aoa").hover(function(){ //hover over list item
    $("#mmAoa100").addClass("hover");  //adds class to shape
}, function(){
    $('#mmAoa100').removeClass("hover"); //removes class from shape
}); 
});
```

This only works in one direction when I hover over the shape with the ID of mmAoa100, not the reverse. Even if it did work, with my current method I would need to duplicate this for all 15 pairs.

My CSS is

```
.mmProp {
  opacity: .2;
}

.mmProp:hover {
  opacity: .7;
  transition-duration: 0.1s;
}

.mmProp.hover {
  opacity: .7;
  transition-duration: 0.1s;
}

.propertyList li.hover {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.propertyList li:hover {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

I've saved it as a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/r3hbchff/

Please help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: To make it cleaner, you could throw out the jQuery and simply add `:hover` to the end of a css selector. See [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to set up some kind of a relationship between the polygons and the anchors. IMHO the design I've chosen to show in this answer is far from good, however it displays very well how the relationship works.

I have created an object with key - value pairs consisting of key being the ID of the polygon and the value being the ID of the anchor that is supposed to get highlighted. Loop through all elements in the object and add event handlers ( define additional `add` and `remove` to save insignificant amounts of ram ).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var relations = {
        mmAoa100: "pl100aoa",
        mmHudson10: "pl1hudson",
        ...
    }

    function add(){
        var elem = this.relationKey ? $("#" + relations[this.relationKey]) : $(this);
        elem.addClass("hover");
    }

    function remove() {
        var elem = this.relationKey ? $("#" + relations[this.relationKey]) : $(this);
        elem.removeClass("hover");
    }

    $.each(relations, function(k, v){
       $("#" + k).hover(add, remove)[0].relationKey = k;
       $("#" + v).hover(add, remove);
    });
});
```

[Updated FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/r3hbchff/2/)

*Note I have only set up two relations.